# rsync --delete not removing all deleted files

Tags: rsync

I am using rsync for backing up several systems, either to external hard drives or over the network to another machine.  The idea is to maintain a replica of the original filesystem, with a few things like /dev, /proc, /mnt, and what not excluded, which is then snapshotted at the destination (i.e. with btrfs or zfs).  To that end, I use a command along the lines of

```
rsync -avP --delete --exclude /dev/* --exclude /proc/* --exclude /mnt/* etc. etc. / backup@fileserver:/mnt/array/backup/machine/
```

Which works reasonably well.  However, I just noticed that rsync is not reliably deleting things on the destination.  As a result, there are many more files on the destination than exist at any time on the source, in one case the back up was 100 GB larger than the source.  The leftover files seem to be mostly old versions of various software and libraries.  For example, on the original machine, /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/ contains

```
5.9.2
QAbstractButton
qabstractbutton.h
....
```

But on the backup target, the same folder contains:

```
5.6.0
5.6.1
5.7.0
5.7.1
5.8.0
5.9.0
5.9.1
5.9.2
QAbstractButton
qabstractbutton.h
```

rsync seems to be copying over the new files just fine, but forgetting to remove all the old ones.  The odd part is that some files are in fact removed (rsync always reports deleting a lot of files when synchronizing) but it seems that many files are not actually deleted.  As a result, my backups are taking up a lot more space than they should, and they can't be directly restored because they can take up more space than the original partition to be due to all the extra files, and things like flat-file package databases are all screwed up, containing many duplicate entries for old versions packages.

Any ideas on what might be going on here?  Is there some other flag I need to pass to rsync so that it actually deletes everything it's supposed to?

Comment: Also, wildcards can be problematic with rsync.

Comment: [rsync doesn't handle wildcards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400990/rsync-delete-not-removing-all-deleted-files/400998?noredirect=1#comment1093220_400998)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some suggestions for things to try come from the contents of the man page (the section about `--delete`). There are a lot of caveats and warnings. Have you considered all of these?

- Works only "for  the directories that are being synchronized". I guess this means they must have a parent/ancestor directory being copied.
- Similarly, it doesn't apply to anything being explicitly excluded:

> Files that are excluded from the transfer are also excluded  from
>   being deleted unless you use the `--delete-excluded`   option  or mark
>   the rules as only matching on the sending side.

- If  the sending side detects any I/O errors, then the deletion of any files at the destination will be automatically disabled. Override with `--ignore-errors`.
- Try with `--dry-run` first? Combine with `--verbose` and closely examine everything that's happening with problem directories.

  > This option can be dangerous if used incorrectly!  It is a very good
  >   idea to first try a  run  using  the  --dry-run option (-n) to see
  >   what files are going to be deleted.

So consider trying `--delete-excluded`, `--ignore-errors`, and/or `--dry-run`/`--verbose`...not necessarily as a "fix" but at the very least there may be helpful data to be gleaned.

Also, take a look at the `--delete-before` flag. This is supposed to do the receive-side deletes before the actual transfer. Again, this might not fix everything but could be revealing. It'd be interesting to see if it helps reduce disk space usage, too.

Comment: Hmm, maybe --ignore-errors is the ticket.  Invariably, rsync runs in to some sort of error with a file disappearing before it can be copied or a gvfs mount point that can't be read by root.  I'll try adding that flag and see what happens.

Comment: Yep, --ignore-errors was the ticket.  Thanks!

Comment: I found, as @Gringo Suave said above as a comment, that wildcards were my issue. I had to use --dry-run and figure out how to rid the wildcard before --delete could work.

Comment: @bafromca What was the particular issue you faced? I think "wildcards can be problematic with rsync" is a bit misleading as it implies there's something tricky about rsync's handling of wildcards. The thing is, rsync _doesn't_ handle them. That's what the shell is for. So make sure each wildcard is visible to the shell (i.e. don't single quote or escape any of them). Then it should be easy to reason about what will happen in rsync, e.g. `--delete` will only delete contents of directories you explicitly name so `foo` or ``foo/`` but not `foo/*`.

Comment: It seems `--delete` with wildcard `foo/*` didn't delete the extraneous files or folders at the destination, so I was left with double the data on my hard drive without the new reorganization I did. I removed the wildcards with `--dry-run` to confirm and it seemed that allowed the extraneous directories and files I wanted to be removed to be removed. So as you said, it was probably my misunderstanding of how the shell expanded the wildcard than rsync and its flags in and of itself.

Comment: @bafromca Cool. You've leveled up your "rsync fu", then. :)

Comment: I was struggling to ensure distant files ARE deleted. I struggled for 2 years. For unknown reasons --ignore-errors solved the issue for me. 
Thanks for your detailed explanation, this was a live saver, I was starting to go crazy here.

Comment: @Autiwa You might want to dig in a little deeper as to why `--ignore-errors` got things working as you wouldn't want to mask some critical issue (an example is mentioned in the man page under `--delete`). That being said, if things are working smoothly I'm glad my answer helped eliminate the source of your frustrations. :)

Comment: @BLayer That's a good point. I tried and I think I know where the error comes from. I have 2 errors like this "rsync: opendir "/local/home/xxx/.dbus failed" (another for .gvfs). And I couldn't figure out how to get rid of this. I don't even want to backup those folders. Addings them to my exclude list changes nothing...

Comment: @Autiwa Hmm. Are you sure  they aren't in your source or target dir set? Because I'm guessing it's just an issue of file permissions. Those directories may be owned by root, for instance. In fact, this person had a very similar error with `rsync` and the D-Bus config dir: https://github.com/bit-team/backintime/issues/1231

Comment: Filters (e.g. excludes) can be tricky to get right so make sure you double check 'em as that would be an adequate workaround IMO. Or, if you don't want to spend another minute on this problem ;) these particular errors seem pretty safe to ignore based on what I've heard to this point.

Comment: Agreed that filters (excludes) are tricky. I tried everything I could think of, and could not solve this issue properly. My inability to debug this was also an issue. It's difficult to fine tune an exclude list if you don't know or understand how it's used... As much as I'd like to understand this, I have more important things to work on so I'm not planning to work on this again, unless I absolutely have to. Thanks a lot for your help and availability.