# rsync not reporting on files to delete

Tags: rsync, delete

I've had a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/706903/228028) (and the forum thread [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1692800)) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400990/rsync-delete-not-removing-all-deleted-files).

I've tried running in Python and also at the command line. I've double-checked: some files have definitely been deleted from the source, but are present in the `link-dest` destination. I've tried messing around with numerous options. I've tried adding forward slash to the end of the paths to see if that might make a difference. The paths in all cases are simple directories, never ending in glob patterns. I've also looked at the man pages.

Incidentally, this shouldn't matter, but you never know: I'm running this under WSL (W10 OS).

Nothing seems to work.

By the way, the files deleted in source ***do*** get deleted (or rather not copied) in the target location (if not a dry run).

What I'm trying to do is to find out what changes have occurred between the `link-dest` location and the source, with a view to cancelling the operation if nothing has changed. But to do that I have to be able to get a list of new or modified files and also files which have been deleted.

This is the Python code I've been trying:

```
link_dest_setting = '' if most_recent_snapshot_of_any_type == None \
    else f'--link-dest={most_recent_snapshot_of_any_type[0]}'
rsync_command_args = [ 'rsync', 
                       '-v', 
                       # '--progress',
                       # '--update', 
                       '--recursive', 
                       '--times', 
                       '--delete', 
                       # '--info=DEL', 
                       '-n', 
    link_dest_setting, source_dir, new_snapshot_path, ]
print( f'running this: {rsync_command_args}')    
result = subprocess.run( rsync_command_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
rsync_result_stdout = result.stdout.decode( 'utf-8' )
print( f'rsync_result stdout |{rsync_result_stdout}|')
rsync_result_stderr = result.stderr.decode( 'utf-8' )
print( f'rsync_result stderr |{rsync_result_stderr}|')
```

Typical `stdout` (with dry run):

```
rsync_result stdout |sending incremental file list
./
MyModifiedFile.odt

sent 1,872 bytes  received 25 bytes  3,794.00 bytes/sec
total size is 6,311,822  speedup is 3,327.27 (DRY RUN)

|
```

(no errors are reported in `stderr`)

Just found another option, `-i`. Using this things get quite mysterious:

```
rsync_result stdout |sending incremental file list
.d..t...... ./
>f.st...... MyModifiedFile.odt

sent 53,311 bytes  received 133 bytes  35,629.33 bytes/sec
total size is 6,311,822  speedup is 118.10
|
```

**Edit**

Typical BASH command:

```
rsync -virtn --delete --link-dest=/mnt/f/link_dest_dir /mnt/d/source_dir /mnt/f/destination_dir
```

Dry run which, in principle, should show files/dirs present under link_dest_dir but NOT present (deleted) under source_dir. I can't get this to be shown. In any event I think the Python answer is likely to be a preferable solution, because the scanning STOPS at the first detection of a difference.

**Edit 2**

(in answer to roaima's question "what are you saving?")
My "My Documents" dir has about 6 GB, and thousands of files. It takes my Python script 15 s or so to scan it, if no differences are found (shorter if one is). `rsync` typically takes about 2 minutes to do a copy (using hard links for the vast majority of the files). If that were found to be unnecessary, because there had been no change between the source and the `link-dest` location, I would then have to delete all those files and hard links. The deletion operation on its own is very expensive in terms of time. Incidentally, this is an external HD, spinning plates type. Not the slowest storage location ever, but it has the limitations it has.

Just as importantly, because `rsync` does not appear to be capable, at least according to what I have found, of reporting on files which have been deleted in the source, how would I even know that this new snapshot was identical to the `link-dest` snapshot? In these snapshot locations I only want to keep a limited number (e.g. 5) snapshots, but I only want to add a new snapshot when it is different to its predecessor.  So although the script may run every 10 minutes, the gap between adjacent snapshots may be 40 minutes, or much longer.

I see you (roaima) have a high rep, and seem to specialise quite a bit in `rsync`. The simple question I want answering is: is it possible for `rsync`, on a dry run or not, to report on files/dirs deleted in the source relative to the `link-dest`? If not, is this a bug/deficiency? Because the man pages certainly seem to claim (e.g. with `--info=DEL`) that this should happen.

Comment: I'm not great with python. What's the actual `rsync` command you're running? What do you want it to do, and what does it seem to be doing? Can you provide some example files (or directory structure) and explain what you want to happen with it?

Comment: What's mysterious about the `-i` output? It's, if anything, easier to parse in a script than the `-v` output.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks, but I don't understand it. Can you explain what these dots and "f", "d", "t" and "s" mean? Preferably with a link to some documentation somewhere. Ideally I would like the **names** of the files absent in the `link-dest` location to be displayed.

Comment: The `d` and the `t` means `./` is a directory and that its timestamp is different. The `f`, `s` and `t` means the ODT file is a file, has a size difference and a timestamp difference. This is described in the `rsync` manual (see tho `-i` or `--itemize-changes` option in there).

Comment: OK thanks, I understand it now.  All 11 dots apply to a single file/directory. Still no indicator of a file missing in the source but present in the `link-dest` location. That's my experience anyway.

Comment: So what you're asking is how to use a comparison between source and link-dest to determine whether or not to run a copy from source to destination. I don't see that this gains you anything. If you've got rsync set up right then a copy from source to destination with no processing should take just moments to scan the list of files' metadata (name, size, mtime). That's going to be about the same effort as comparing source and link-dest. `rsync` won't copy files unnecessarily. Either (a) what am I missing, or (b) what are you saving?

Comment: OK, the answer to that is long enough that I have to give it in an edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key parts of your question seem to be these,

> I only want to add a new snapshot when it is different to its predecessor. So although the script may run every 10 minutes, the gap between adjacent snapshots may be 40 minutes, or much longer

and

> Is it possible for rsync, on a dry run or not, to report on files or directories deleted in the source relative to the link-dest

What I'm understanding here is that you have implemented a version of `rsnapshot`, where each time you consider taking a backup, the *previous* backup directory becomes your `--link-dest` directory. The big difference being that if there are no changes between the current source tree and the most recent backup, then in your case no backup is to be taken.

In my short experiment it seems to be possible simply to look at the output of `rsync`: if there is output there is work to be done, and if not there isn't. The key though is to look directly at the link directory

```
output=$(rsync -rti --delete --dry-run "$src/" "$lnk/" 2>&1 | grep -v '^[^*]d' | head -n1)
if [ -n "$output" ]
then
    # Work to be done
    rsync -rtiv --link-dest "$lnk/" "$src/" "$dst"
fi
```

At the moment I've omitted directories from the test, so a change to a directory will not trigger a backup. If you care about changes to directories too, remove the `grep` filter from the test

Comment: Thanks. In Linux I've used Timeshift, indeed. Actually it's not *exactly* like you describe, in the sense that although I compare with the previous snapshot of the particular time category (10-minutes, hour, day, week, month, etc.) for the purpose of identifying differences, I actually use the most recent snapshot in *any* time category for the non-dry `rsync` op ... since it seems to me that using the most recent snapshot will result in the most hard links and the fewest file copy operations. Will do some experiments with your solution later.

Comment: Hmmm... ! Sorry to say so, but when I modify or add a file in the `src` location (i.e. somewhere in the directory tree), this results in a non-dry run, work to be done. But if I delete a file in the `src` somewhere in the tree, `output` is indeed a blank string! Can you possibly see whether you have different results in your system? I'm really puzzled whether this is just my system or whether `rsync` seemingly fails to identify deletions as (it would appear from the docs) it is intended to.

Comment: I'm so sorry; I missed a final update to my `grep` when transferring from my test rig to here. Answer modified for you

Comment: Thanks, working now. So the conclusion seems to be that the reporting of deletions (and additions and modifications, presumably) is relative to the destination location, not to the `link-dest` location. This is probably clear from the man docs ...

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's fundamentally about copying from source to destination, and the link-dest is purely to help speed things on their way

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a workaround, as it uses Python. I have been experimenting with both `diff` and `rsync` most of the day. I simply cannot get `rsync` to report on files/directories which have been deleted in the source and are present in the `link-dest` location (e.g. in a dry run). `diff` does seem to do the job, but can be very lengthy with big directories, and there is no way for you to say "stop if you find a difference". The same applies to `rsync` for that matter.

```
import filecmp

def same_folders(dcmp):
    if dcmp.diff_files or dcmp.left_only or dcmp.right_only:
        return False
    for sub_dcmp in dcmp.subdirs.values():
        if not same_folders(sub_dcmp):
            return False
    return True

if same_folders(filecmp.dircmp( source_dir, link_dest_dir_path )):
    print( 'NO CHANGE' )
    # ... act accordingly
```

First experiments seem to show that this is a blindingly fast way to find a difference between two directories. Incidentally, I haven't yet looked into what sort of difference function is used to produce `dircmp.diff_files` (which lists files with the same paths but which differ).

`left_only` and `right_only` are about finding new files/directories in the source or ones which have been deleted from the source, respectively.

This obviously stops the second it finds a difference.

I know BASH **much** less than Python... I wonder if a BASH equivalent to the above is possible? Then it would be interesting to do a speed comparison...

Comment: Added example. I am trying to find whether there is a difference (any difference) between two directories (including their subtrees). If a difference is detected I would *then* do a proper (non-dry-run) rsync run.